# How to create an accessor for pivot field in larval 10.x?

Tags: php, casting, accessor, laravel-10

I have two models:

- User
- Place
  and a Pivot as:
- Role(user_id, place_id, type)
  and an example of type is "["manager", "reception"]" and i want to change this value to collection when retriving as:
  `Place::find(1)->users[0]->pivot->type`

i add this method but it doesn't work and return string:

```
    public function getTypeAttribute($value){
        return collect(json_decode($value));
    }
```

Comment: Is it your pivot table is working fine? If yes then try to debug the code first

Comment: yes it is work fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot to use `using`. It should be like this:
`$this->belongsToMany(Place::class, 'roles', 'place_id', 'user_id')->using(Role::class)->withPivot('type');`